# SurfaceView and autofocus

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, autofocus

I am writing an app where I need to show in a layer what the cam is viewing so I use the basic code of surfaceView/surfaceHolder. My problem is that I would like to have autofocus enabled but althought I have looked for a solution on the net I don't know how to implement it yet. I have seen that android has a parameter for it and so I have put it in surfaceCreated method as you can see but it doesn't make any difference. What it surprises to me is that my mobile contains focus_mode_auto but this solution doesn't work. Any idea? I would like to use min sdk = 9 so avoid implementions of api 14/15.

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    List<String> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
    // I have also tried with FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO
    if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO))
    {
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
    }
    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    setCameraDisplayOrientation(this, CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, camera);
}
```

NOTE: I do have

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

in manifest and If I do a handler to focus every second it focus the image but when it is called, first you can see that the image loses its focus and then it gains it so it is very annoying.

Comment: No, I didn't. Anyway I stopped that project and by the way, I suppose that now it would not be necessary to restrict to sdk=9 as there is little demand on it: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=suzunone